# mod_rewrite RewriteRule for abc.php?a=1&b=2 to abc/2.html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am a real newbie to the either mod_rewrite or Regex.
Therefore I just need your help for the following problem.

I got a PHP-Page that looks just like:

```
stuff.php?id=1&text=2
```

I know want to to look like

```
stuff/2.html
```

Do anyone of you have the RewriteRule line for the htaccess in mind to let it look just like this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: And `id=1` has no meaning?

Comment: Yes exactly. id=1 is just for stuff.php to know which entry to take from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite rule for this particular page:

```
RewriteRule ^stuff/2\.html$ stuff.php?id=1&text=2
```

And if `2` should be dynamic:

```
RewriteRule ^stuff/([0-9]+)\.html stuff.php?id=1&text=$1
```

**A little explanation:**

- `^` and `$` stand for start and end of the string, so we don't match `longstuff/2.html.php`.
- The dot has to be escaped `\.` because otherwise it has a special meaning in  RegEx ("any character")
- the parantheses in the second pattern are a "capture group", their content will be available in the rewrite as `$n` (with `n` = number of capture group, in this case `1`)
- `[0-9]` is a character class, matches one character of the class, in this case a digit
- `+` means "one or more"

Comment: What if I need either id=[X] and text=[Y]?

If I have the rewritten URL to be like stuff/[NUMERIC_ID]/[TEXT] to link to stuff.php?id=[NUMERIC_ID]&text=[TEXT]?

Comment: That's why I asked about the meaning of id=1 ... use a second capture group and `$2`

Comment: I thought it from the "wrong way" with the right block to just being displayed as the left block.
Sorry about that

Comment: What do you think of the following:

    RewriteRule ^stuff/([0-9]{1,}+)_(.*)\.html?$ stuff.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

Comment: It's either `{1,}` or `+` (same meaning), not both together. Other than that the rule is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rule to redirect `stuff/2.html` to `stuff.php?id=1&text=2`

```
RewriteRule ^stuff/([\d]+)\.html$ stuff.php?id=1&text=$1 [L]
```

Notice `[\d]+` will only accept numbers, if you want to allow letters and caret, use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^stuff/([\w-]+)\.html$ stuff.php?id=1&text=$1 [L]
```